# Internally load balance Docker Containers using Azure Container Service

Tags: azure, docker

I am using Azure Container Service with Docker Swarm to host some containers. The containers are running ASP.NET Core Web API and have a private port exposed. I am trying to use Haproxy as an internal load balancer in front of these containers which in turn is exposed through port 8080 on Azure Container Service.

Here is the haproxy.cfg

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1   local0
   log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
   #log loghost    local0 info
   maxconn 4096
   chroot /usr/local/etc/haproxy
   uid 99
   gid 99

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:8080
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    server server1 10.0.0.4:8080 maxconn 32
    server server1 10.0.0.5:8080 maxconn 32
    server server1 10.0.0.6:8080 maxconn 32
```

Comment: Docker 1.12 has Swarm built into the engine with an internal load balancer. It's a release candidate but might be worth trying out?

Answer (score 0):

With Docker Swarm as an orchestrator, ACS already creates Load Balancers (separate for Agents and Masters) in your swarm based cluster. You do not need to worry about it anymore.

See the sample demonstration here:
"[Microsoft Azure Container Service Engine - Swarm Walkthrough](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/swarm.md)"